# How to make translations qml

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make translations on my toolbar. The toolbar is a listmodel:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

    ListModel {
        id:tBar
     ListElement {
            buttonText: QT_TR_NOOP("Cars In Speed Function")
            bottomText: ""
            event: "carsInSpdFn"
            buttonLevel: "0"
            buttonBurst: false
            icon: "qrc:/icons/histogram_128x128_w.png"
            color: "#369c3b"
            active: true

            permissionLevel: 0
        }
        ListElement {
            buttonText: QT_TR_NOOP("Clear all logs")
            bottomText: ""
            event: "cleraAllLogs"
            buttonLevel: "0"
            buttonBurst: false
            icon: "qrc:/icons/trash_128x128_w.png"
            color: "steelblue"
            active: true

            permissionLevel: 3
        }
```

The list is called in file to property variant value.
Main file:

```
/..
DynamicApp{
    id: statistics
    objectName: "Statistics"
    toolbarModel: ToolbarModel{}




    title:  qsTr("Statistics management")
    icon:   "qrc:/icons/statistics_128x128_w.png"
../
```

The DynamicApp is the qml file where is defined window of the app. There is defined toolbarModel which is "property variant".
DynamicApp:

```
/..
Rectangle {
    id: app
    width: main.width
    height: main.height
    color: layout_id.bgColor
    opacity: 0    

    property variant parameter;
    property bool useToolbar: true
    property bool useTopbar: true
    property bool activeApp: false

    property variant toolbarModel
    property string title: ""
    property string icon: ""
../
```

I know how to translate model lists by qsTr or qsTranslate but I don't know how to cal it into property variant becouse there is calling into all file toolbarModel. 
Can you explain me how to translate this list in my app?

Answer (score 1):

For the translations you need to add it into your APP.pro. You need to do a hack to add the QML translations so lupdate can actually reach them. For example, in our project we have:

```
# English
TRANSLATIONS += settings/language/set_language/setting_en.ts
# Spanish
TRANSLATIONS += settings/language/set_language/setting_es.ts
```

After, to include in the lupdate the qml files, we do a trick found on internet

```
evil_hack_hahaha_add_what_ever_you_want_etc {
SOURCES += path_to_qml/*.qml \
    path_to_qml2/*.qml \
    ...
}
```

After, run in console

```
lupdate NAMEOFPROFILE.pro
```

Now you will have generate the .ts including the ones for qml.

After doing your translation job, remember to

```
lrelease NAMEOFPROFILE.pro
```

Good luck!